# Store html code to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a problem when converting store html code to javascript variable, I know we can convert using converter tools, but I can't use this converter in my situation.

I am trying the following code

```js
var t_cls="font-effect-anaglyph rotator";
var randompostsurl="www.allinworld99.blogspot.com";
var randompoststitle="Open Inspect Element And see the Code";
var default_script = "<script> document.write('<div><a  class="+t_cls+" href=\"' + randompostsurl + '\" rel=\"nofollow\">' + randompoststitle + '<\/a><\/div>'); <\/script>\n";

$("#apnd").append(default_script);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="apnd"></div>
```

The above one will produce the following **output**

```
<a class="font-effect-anaglyph" rotator="" href="www.allinworld99.blogspot.com" rel="nofollow">Open Inspect Element And see the Code</a>
```

Why the rotator class will created as new attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are no quotes around the `class` attribute in the result. You need to add them, since you have a space in the attribute's value:

```
default_script = "<script>        document.write('<div><a class=\""+t_cls+"\" href=\"' + randompostsurl + '\" rel=\"nofollow\">' + randompoststitle + '<\/a><\/div>');<\/script>\n";
// Here --------------------------------------------------------^^---------^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your default_script code

```
 default_script = "<script>        document.write('<div><a class='"+t_cls+"' href=\"' + randompostsurl + '\" rel=\"nofollow\">' + randompoststitle + '<\/a><\/div>');<\/script>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are no quotes in class, it produce rotator as a new attribute. But you can achieve rotator as a class by the following way. i.e replacing single quotes with escape sequence.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
 var t_cls="font-effect-anaglyph rotator", randompostsurl="www.allinworld99.blogspot.com",
 randompoststitle="Open Inspect Element And see the Code",
 default_script = "document.write(\"<div><a class=\""+t_cls+"\" href=\"" + randompostsurl + "\" rel=\"nofollow\">\" + randompoststitle + \"<\/a><\/div>\");<\/script>\n";
$("#apnd").append(default_script);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That will produce a `document.write` statement that will fail when executed, as what it produces looks like this: `document.write("<div><a class="font-effect-anaglyph rotator" href="www.allinworld99.blogspot.com" rel="nofollow">" + randompoststitle + "</a></div>");</script>`

Comment: The error is Fixed T.J.Crowder. Thank you for reminding :)

Comment: No, the error isn't fixed. :-) The answer hasn't been changed since I posted my comment, and the problem remains.